# How to make a jQuery autocomplete's results go away immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a jQuery autocomplete field on one of my pages. When I'm focused on the autocomplete field and I hit tab, it takes a little bit for the list of results to go away. Also, if I hit enter in the autocomplete field, the results stick around forever.

Is there an easy, preferably built-in way to make the result list go away immediately when the field loses focus or when I press enter? I could write my own solution by observing the blur and keypress events but it seems like something that would probably already be out there.

Comment: Which one of the many jQuery Autocomplete plugins are you using?

Comment: Good question. This one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: That plugin doesn't exhibit any of the behaviour you describe on their example page.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. The problem is solved now, though, so I guess it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ac_results").css("display", "none");
```